# uploads folder wordpress dont work anymore?

Tags: wordpress

```
has failed to upload due to an error
Unable to create directory /Volumes/Local/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/02. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

the last thing i remember i did was on localhost, deleted the uploads folder...
now the uploads folder is gone, i keep getting this error,
while i made sure in the settings i have wp-content/uploads
i tried to create a folder manually, or change the directory...

but all says its parents directory writeable by the server????? wordpress deny to create the upload folder again : /

how to solve this?

Comment: have you checked the folder's permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok solved this.

For any who is using MAMP Pro and u need file permission of Wordpress for your uploads folder.
Go to HOST Tab - and click your localhost - there you find a button with **permissions**.
set `Owner and Group to www` and enable it with set.

In wordpress - under media settings, change your current folder to where ever you want. example: `../uploads`   this goes right direct in the root/uploads. click on save and you are done and all should work.

For Filezilla when your site is online. Once you connected, rightclick on the upload folder and change the permissions there.

Thats it. 1 min work >< took me half a day of research. And most anwsers on forums/posts etc are way too complicated.

This is the quickest and best way using Mamp pro and Filezilla.

Comment: For me there was an incorrect path under Settings > Media as I had imported the WordPress instance from our website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the folder permissions to `755` or on some servers `777` using:

`chmod 755` or `chmod 777` on the folder in question.